# Jquery Required Dependency Expression

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to make a field required only if another field is answered in a specific way.
In the first example, the dependent field is a radio button with the ID statusc, forcing a text field, male1 to become required.
The following does not work:

```
 male1: {
              required: "#statusc: checked"
        }
```

I cannot see why this will not work for me as it seems to follow the exact method shown in many examples I have read. However, there is obviously something I'm missing or misunderstanding!

My second situation is where the dependent field is a select option:
For example:
Field #name is only required when option B is selected from the drop down options A B C D E etc?

I might also need to use the rule where both dependent and required fields are text fields so I would be very grateful if someone could explain the method for all required-dependency situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency expressions do not support whitespace between the element id and the selector filter. You should write:

```
male1: {
    required: "#statusc:checked"
}
```

When the dependent field is more complex than a radio button, you can provide a *dependency callback function* that implements your own validation mechanism and returns `true` if the element is deemed valid:

```
name: {
    required: function() {
        return $("#yourDropDown").val() == "B";
    }
}
```

Dependency callbacks can handle any validation scheme you can think of (since you're providing the validation algorithm's implementation), so you can use them to handle all required dependency situations.